# Is there any eraser button in libreoffice

Tags: 12.10, libreoffice

I know this looks like an idiotic questions. But I need to know. Before shifting to Ubuntu in Microsoft word theres a eraser button in doc menu which I used several times. But in Ubuntu libreoffice I can't find anything like it. Is it exist in it? Or I have to use another one which have this button. Then please suggest me another program.

Comment: There is a windows version of libreoffice. And the cool thing about free software is, well, that its free. Just download it, give it a try and if you like it keep it. Your choice... ain't that cool?! Oh, and switch to Ubuntu :-)

Comment: In LibreOffice Writer in its Table Toolbar there is a merge-button. If I understand it well, that's what the eraser button in ms word is supposed to do do.: erase the cell border, so that the cells are merged. (I don't use ms word, so I can be wrong.) As hmayag writes: install LibreOffice on a windows pc, and give it a try.

Comment: I am not using windows anymore and thanks merge-button is the one I am looking for. Please post this as an answer. @Frank

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In LibreOffice Writer in its Table Toolbar there is a merge-button.

If I understand it well, that's what the eraser button in ms word is supposed to do do.: erase the cell border, so that the cells are merged.

(I don't use ms word, so I can be wrong.)

As hmayag writes: install LibreOffice on a windows pc, and give it a try.